# Как сделать функцию команды из админки перезагрузить страницу?

Tags: ajax, php

Как при добавлении контента или изменения настроек в сетингс в админке дать команду на странице обновиться?

Comment: @Bridun, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: Почитайте про связку php + ajax, это самый распространённый способ обновления информации и страницу при этом обновлять не нужно, можно обновлять только нужные данные из базы и через js добавлять их на страницу, вот для примера тема: http://hashcode.ru/questions/392202/

Comment: @Bridun, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript

```
setTimeout( function(){
       window.location.reload();
},1000);
```

Или php

```
header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); 
        exit;
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, не подходит такое.

Надо, чтоб при нажатии кнопки из админки дать команду обновиться на главной странице.

Comment: @Leagnus,

    exit(header('Location:http://url'));

Answer (score 1):

Есть один способ, правда, он не очень хороший с точки зрения производительности. На главной странице создайте скрипт, который, допустим, раз в минуту будет отправлять ajax запрос на сервер. В админке по выполнению какого-то действия вы в БД добавляете таск - обновить страницу и/или url. В обработчике ajax вы смотрите в БД, извлекаете таск и на главной странице посредством js обновляете или перенаправляете страницу.

Answer (score 0):

У первого ответа есть минусы. JS может быть отключен, а для PHP header() необходимо, чтобы вывода до выполнения функции не было. Поэтому можете воспользоваться следующим решением:

```
<?php
    print '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://example.com/">';
?>
```

Атрибут content принимает два параметра, но может и один, первый время в секундах, через сколько обновить, второй собственно ссылку перехода, например, на другую страницу, если url не указывать, то страница просто обновится.

Comment: "JS может быть отключен" - сейчас это из разряда фантастики, потому что 90% сайтов без JS будут выглядеть очень плохо, а некоторые вообще не будут работать